# How to add component onclick on multiple times in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to add div with three text box, and this div need to be added again and again when add branch button is clicked, Like wise how to do it and get value from it ?

my code:

```js
<div className="form-group">
  <label>Store Address</label>
  <input type="text"
         value={this.state.input.address1}
         onChange={this.handleChange}  
         className="form-control code" name="address1" placeholder="Pincode" />   
  <span className="form-text" id="errtext">{this.state.errors.address1}</span>                                             
</div>
<div className="form-group">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col">
      <input type="text" className="form-control code"
             value={this.state.input.address2}
             onChange={this.handleChange} 
             name="address2" placeholder="address" />
      <span className="form-text" id="errtext">{this.state.errors.address2}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-auto">
      <p style={{margin:"5px"}}>and</p>
    </div>
    <div className="col">
      <SimpleModal className="form-control" mapFunctionHere={this.mapFunctionHere} />   
    </div>
    
  </div>                
</div>
<div className="form-group">                                               
  <input type="text"
         className="form-control code"
         value={this.state.MapAddr}
         onChange={this.handleChange} 
         name="address3" placeholder="address" readOnly />     
  <span className="form-text" id="errtext">{this.state.errors.address3}</span>           
</div>
```

It is the div code which to be added multiple times when i click :

```js
<input type="button" className="addbranch"  onClick={this.appendDiv} value="Add Branch" />
```

when add branch is clicked once the above div should appear once, if button is clicked twice then it should appear twice, I need to do like the above and validate the field and get values, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a counter in your state which increases every time, when you click the button until the limit is reached.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0,
    values: [
      { address1: { value: '', error: ''}, address2: { value: '', error: '' }, address3: { value: '', error: '' } }
    ]
  }
  
  handleChangeInput = (counter, key, value) => {
    const newValues = [...this.state.values]
    newValues[counter][key].value = value
    this.setState({ values: newValues })
  }

  renderBranch = counter => {
    const { values } = this.state
    return (
      <>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Store Address</label>
          <input type="text"
            value={values[counter].address1.value}
            onChange={event => this.handleChangeInput(counter, 'address1', event.target.value)}  
            className="form-control code"
            name="address1"
            placeholder="Pincode"
          />   
          <span className="form-text" id="errtext">
            {values[counter].address1.error}    
          </span>                                             
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <input type="text" className="form-control code"
                value={values[counter].address2.value}
                onChange={event => this.handleChangeInput(counter, 'address2', event.target.value)}
                name="address2"
                placeholder="address" />
              <span className="form-text" id="errtext">
                {values[counter].address2.error}    
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>  
          <div className="col-md-auto">
            <p style={{margin:"5px"}}>and</p>
            <div className="col">
              <SimpleModal className="form-control" mapFunctionHere={this.mapFunctionHere}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">                                               
          <input type="text"
            className="form-control code"
            value={values[counter].address3.value}
            onChange={event => this.handleChangeInput(counter, 'address2', event.target.value)}
            name="address3"
            placeholder="address"
            readOnly
          />     
          <span className="form-text" id="errtext">
            {values[counter].address3.error}    
          </span>           
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
  
  renderBranches = () => {
    const { counter } = this.state
    const result = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
      result.push(this.renderBranch(i))
    }
    return result
  }
  
  appendDiv = () => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1,
      values: [
        ...this.state.values,
        { address1: { value: '', error: ''}, address2: { value: '', error: '' }, address3: { value: '', error: '' } }
      ]
    })
  }
  
  render = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {this.renderBranches()}
        <input type="button" className="addbranch"  onClick={this.appendDiv} value="Add Branch" />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: But values appearing are same on both div, If i type in the first div the same value automatically appear in second div too, i need separate data and i need to validate it

Comment: Yeah, thats what I wrote above. You need different data structure in state with handle change functions which just update one specific value. If you need help with that, let me know.

Comment: Okay. Give me a few minutes, I will update my comment above when I am finished.

Comment: Okay I am looking into it

Comment: Sorry, I did multiple mistakes before. I updated my answer. Maybe my solution is not the best, but it should work for you. You should be able now, to implement the validation.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'address1' of undefined Error message

Comment: If you copied my code this should work. I can compile it without any problems.

Comment: In address 3 i am getting value from another component and displaying here so that value repeats here  <div className="form-group">                                               
              <input type="text"
                className="form-control code"
                value={MapAddr}
                onChange={event => this.handleChangeInput(counter, 'address3', MapAddr)}
                name="address3"
                placeholder="address"
                readOnly
              />     I need to get different values

Comment: please look at it

Comment: I need the full code to help your with this.